# Converting string to int in python

Tags: python

```
a="1234"
for i in range(0,4):
            for k in range(i,4):
                s=int(a[i:k])
                print s
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/Solutions/test.py", line 4, in <module>
    s=int(a[i:k])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

can anybody tell me why  I am getting this error ?
i just want to print:
1
12
123
1234
2
23
234
and so on...

Comment: Because e.g. `a[0:0]` is an empty string `''` and `int('')` makes no sense. What output were you expecting?

Comment: What is your code trying to do?

Comment: cant you simply use int(a)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse String to Float or Int](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/379906/parse-string-to-float-or-int)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are receiving this error because the first iteration of your loop `(i=0,k=0)` takes `a[0:0]=''` (empty string). Characters and numerical strings can be converted to integers, but an empty string isn't a character or string. It's the absence of characters.

If you were to guard this case your loop would subsequently take substrings of a `(example '123', i=0, k=3)` and this could be converted to the integer 123. The rest of the cases should output the desired integers just fine.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> a= "1234"
>>> a[0:0]   # in slice if start and end is same you will get empty string
''
>>> int(a[0:0])
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
>>>
```

i think you want this??

```
>>> for i in range(3):
...     for k in range(i,4):
...         print int(a[i:k+1])
... 
1
12
123
1234
2
23
234
3
34
```